# How to extract RGB from hex in C?

Tags: c

I have a hex color such as 0xaabbcc as a uint32_t and I want to extract the individual RGB components so I want 0xaa, 0xbb and 0xcc. This is how I'm doing it:

```
    uint32_t color_hex = ((uint32_t)0xaabbcc);
    uint8_t red = (uint8_t)((color_hex >> 16) & 0xFF);
    uint8_t green = (uint8_t)((color_hex >> 8) & 0xFF);
    uint8_t blue = (uint8_t)(color_hex & 0xFF);
    
    // Then I'm doing an i2c write with red, green and blue where the function accepts a uint8_t
    i2c_write(<addr>, <reg>, &red);
    i2c_write(<addr>, <reg>, &green);
    i2c_write(<addr>, <reg>, &blue);
```

The values of red, green and blue are not 0xaa, 0xbb and 0xcc respectively. I'm getting 0xcd, 0xce and 0xcf. Can someone help me?

Comment: you have too many unnecessary casts and parentheses

Comment: @phuclv that shouldn't affect why my values are wrong though

Comment: of course I know. That's why it's just a comment to note that it'll greatly reduce readability for more complex code. Anyway you should add information about the platform you're using because the `i2c_write` function I found doesn't receive 3 parameters like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies with the way you use the `i2c_write` function.

You say it accepts at `uint8_t`, but pass a `uint8_t *` as the argument.

Instead of

```
i2c_write(<addr>, <reg>, &red);
```

you should do

```
i2c_write(<addr>, <reg>, red);
```

It would make sense that the three value you get are arbitrary, but are sequential numbers, since `red`, `green`, and `blue` are all likely stored as single adjacent bytes.

Assuming that the function is properly declared with arguments, the pointer is being truncated to the lowest byte.

---

Assuming that the function is declared with arguments, I would expect that the compiler would raise a warning/error about this, passing an integer as a pointer function argument. If not, you should increase the level of warnings emitted by your compiler. Always pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I changed it to use `i2c_write(<addr>, <reg>, red);` but the value is still wrong :(

Comment: @innyme What are the values you get now? Its a sufficient change that the result should be completely different.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change my color back to what I'm actually using instead of aabbcc which looks like white. This solved the problem - thank you so much!